# Put shell script for loop statement for multiple files in a function

Tags: shell, posix

```
#!/bin/sh

if [[ -d "$path" ]]; then
  cd "$path" && echo "$PWD"
  for file in *.jpg *.png *.jpeg *.gif *.gifv *.bmp; do 
    mv "$file" "$destpath"
  done
fi
```

1. Since there are no arrays in POSIX defined. Can I put the `*.jpg *.png *.jpeg *.gif *.gifv *.bmp;` in a function? Because I am using these multiple times in a script.
2. Is it possible to refactor `cd "$path" && echo "$PWD"` in my example? e.g. get rid of the `cd` command but still achieve the same effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works for multiple file types

```
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,gifv,bmp}; do
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`ls *.jpg *.png *.jpeg *.gif *.gifv *.bmp`** this syntax instead of making a array.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -d "$path" ]]; then
    cd "$path" && echo "$PWD"
    for file in `ls *.jpg *.png *.jpeg *.gif *.gifv *.bmp`; do
        mv "$file" "$destpath"
    done
fi
```

**Note:** The **destpath** is should be a absolute path. If not, the destpath is treated as just a string.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but this wasn't my intention. Using `ls` to get results for a `for-loop` is no recommended solution. And I wanted to refactor it to using it in multiple places, thats why I asked for a function.